# iUI virtual keyboard GO button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iui

i am using asp.net and iUI to make a very simple webapp. Everything works fine, except one problem. I have a login form, where user has to enter email and password and press login button. Because user is entering data in a smartphone, he/she can press GO button instead of hinding keyboard and pressing login button.
Problem is, that if user presses the GO button ant login data is wrong, page postbacks and shows second toolbas title. If login data is good, iUI shows two toolbars in the second page.
how can i solve this problem?

P.S. For button i am using LinkedButton, because i have to do some work in codebehind (check login data in database).

Comment: How do you validate "if login data is good" ?

Comment: I validate it in codebehind. I just check if there is a user with login data provided in database and if not - show error, if user exists - redirect to another page.

Comment: If i understand well, when user press GO button on virtual keyboard, it acts like submit button. Instead of that i need i to act like Login button click. If i could achieve that, my problem would probably be solved.

Comment: Okay, if your set your login button as the only submit button on the page, then the GO button will trigger that login "click"